# Entity Admin UI as Node Tab Link

Tags: nodes, navigation

I have an entity "metric" that has specified the following admin ui config:

```
'uri callback' => 'metric_entity_uri',
    'admin ui' => array(
        'path' => 'node/%/config',
        'controller class' => 'MetricEntityUIController',
 ),
```

Now I'm trying to add that node/%/config link as a tab on my node pages next to "View" and "Edit" via hook_menu:

```
$items['node/%node/config'] = array(
    'title' => 'Admin UI',
    'page callback' => 'metric_entity_uri',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, I guess because the path is already taken, it works if I take another path/callback thats not used yet. What do I have to change to get my link working?